# Oracle EBS R12.2 - Should I use the APPS synonym when selecting data from custom tables in Oracle Forms/Reports?

Tags: oracle, upgrade

I have been analysing the changes that need to be performed in the customer custom code before upgrading from EBS 12.1 to 12.2 with focus on online patching compliance.

When running the ‘Online Patching Database Standards Checker ADZDDBCC.sql’, section SECTION-26 list a number of custom database objects to be amended. This section states that ‘Query/DML statements must access tables via the APPS table synonym.’.
Database objects residing in a registered custom schema (i.e. XXSCHEMA) will need to be amended to select data via the APPS table synonym. I understand that and we have a plan in place to sort out those violations.

Now, when running the GSCC checks for custom Oracle forms and reports the same violation is presented but they only point to standard EBS schemas i.e. INV.table_name which we will need to amend to APPS.table_name. The GSCC outputs do not display any violation against registered custom schemas in forms and reports i.e. accessing a table via our XXSCHEMA is not listed in the GSCC results.

We are in doubt if Oracle forms and reports could select data from the custom tables (registered schemas) directly i.e. XXSCHEMA.table_name without using the APPS synonym as this is not listed in the GSCC results.

Can anyone advise please?

Regards, Tiago

Comment: They could.  It's safe as long as you don't try to patch your custom tables using online patching. But you should use the APPS synonyms anyway.  Why wouldn't you want to?

Comment: Hi Matthew, the only reason will be the effort we will need to put into changing the forms/reports, there are hundreds of customs ones but I do agree with you that we should change them otherwise we wouldn't be full compliant with online patching

Answer (score 0):

**EBS 12.2 is just a continuation of the standard that custom forms and reports should reference the APPS owned objects**

It is just good practice to fix forms and reports that do not point at the APPS editioned view in lieu of pointing at the EBS table (e.g. apps.per_all_people_f in lieu of hr.per_all_people_f or apps.custom_table1 in lieu of xxschema.custom_table1).

Since forms and reports will be executed using APPS with the end user's context, it is advocated that one not qualify the editioned view (e.g. just use per_all_people_f).  References to registered schemas which are custom should also follow this practice.

**Why?**

-Oracle EBS security is all based on APPS.  When an end users logs in to EBS, a session context is set which defines the person's access.

Oracle has historically advocated that customizations should use APPS owned objects because the customization (e.g. Form or Report) will then leverage the user's context during execution to produce result sets that correspond with the end user's privileges.

-With EBS 12.2 pushing out online patching and its many components, Oracle steers us to continue to use this APPS centric approach (typically it is the editioned views owned by APPS). Not using the APPS editioned view could result in erroneous results.

One can query your editions:

```
SELECT level,
de.edition_name,
de.parent_edition_name,
de.usable
FROM dba_editions de
START WITH de.edition_name = 'ORA$BASE'
CONNECT BY PRIOR de.edition_name = de.parent_edition_name
ORDER BY de.edition_name
```

Keep in mind that by not referencing the APPS editioned view of the seeded or custom table can result multiplying the number of records back (distorting the functioning of forms and reports).

Moving forward, one should just assume that Online patching will be the new patching methodology used (it is the supported one). With that assumption, referencing the APPS editioned view is a reasonable, defensive approach.

Comment: Really appreciated your comment Patrick, the GSCC checks indeed pointed out violations where we will need to amend Oracle standard schemas to use apps synonym i.e. inv.table_name to apps.table_name

However my doubt here is if I need to amend custom tables as well (registered schemas) i.e. myshema.table_name to apps.table_name in forms and reports as the GSCC checks do not point out this as a violation but in my mind this should be modified to the apps synonym which points to the editioned view

Comment: Maybe the GSCC checks are not able to detect such violation, just giving an example below, XXAC_TEST.fmb has a select statement on a table under INV as well as a few select statements on tables sitting in a custom schema which are not displayed in the GSCC output:
File: /u01/oracle/xxx/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/forms/US/XXAC_TEST.fmb
Errors (1):
   File.Gen.41 (Code Reviewers: CODE_REVIEWER)
      183 - Standards violation found in Query/DML. The direct reference
         inv.mtl_item_locations needs to be updated to use the APPS synonym.

Comment: Sounds like you could raise a service request to see why the GSCC check appears to not be working properly.

Comment: BTW, I updated my answer to more directly answer your question. Again, not sure why the GSCC is not detecting these custom objects which are not referencing the apps editioned view.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I indeed raised a SR a few days back but they keep sending links to different docs, details about online patching I am aware etc even when I ask direct yes/no questions they find a way to avoid my concern.At the end I just gave up as I couldn't get a proper answer from them. 
There are lots of forms/reports to amend in order to make reference to the apps synonym but I do agree its the safest approach.

Comment: We do not have a 12.2 environment as yet but as far as I understood, the impact of not changing these references could result in the forms/report querying/manipulating a column which is being changed (i.e. data length) by a patch (custom change) which MAY result in issues. Would you be aware of any other potential issues? I see this one as a very unlikely thing to happen.

Comment: Yes, I think you have identified the biggest risk (which is not too common). Also, the standards for naming database objects are slightly different than pre-12.2. If your custom database objects are in violation of that, sticking with them could cause somethings to break (including in these forms or reports).